# Enhanced ecommerce not reporting data to google analytics swift

Tags: swift

I have integrated google analytics in my app. google analytics is working perfectly but when it comes to enhanced ecommerce it is not reporting revenue to google analytics i tried my best to find the solution but no got succeeded yet. any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
 private func logCheckoutProgress(){

        var products = [[String:Any]]()

        for product in CartManager.sharedInstance.cart {
            products.append(product.getFirebaseProductForCart())
        }

        let ecommerce = [
            "items" : products,
            AnalyticsParameterCheckoutStep : 2, // Optional for first step.
            AnalyticsParameterCheckoutOption : "COD" // Optional.
            ] as [String : Any]
        Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventCheckoutProgress, parameters: ecommerce)
    }
    private func logPurchases(){

        var products = [[String:Any]]()

        for product in CartManager.sharedInstance.cart {
            products.append(product.getFirebaseProductForCart())
        }

        let subtotal = (confirmedOrder?.subTotal ?? CartManager.sharedInstance.cartSubTotalAmount()) - (PersistenceManager.sharedInstance.promotion()?.calculateDiscount() ?? 0)
        var ecommerce = [
            "items" : products,
            AnalyticsParameterTransactionID : confirmedOrder?.displayId ?? 0,
            AnalyticsParameterAffiliation : PersistenceManager.sharedInstance.vendor()?.name ?? "",
            AnalyticsParameterValue : subtotal,
            AnalyticsParameterCurrency : AppConstants.Currency,
            AnalyticsParameterShipping : CartManager.sharedInstance.doesQualifiesFreeDelivery() ? PersistenceManager.sharedInstance.vendor()?.deliveryCharges ?? 0 : 0,
            ] as [String : Any]

        if let promoCode = PersistenceManager.sharedInstance.promotion()?.promoCode {
            ecommerce[AnalyticsParameterCoupon] = promoCode
        }

        Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventEcommercePurchase, parameters: ecommerce)
    }
```